# How to fill multiple cells in a single row based on one input?

Tags: excel

I'm wondering how I can fill multiple cells (non-consecutive) in a single row with a single input.
So for instance I would like to be able to type in a 1 in cell A1 and then have cell B1 be filled in with a value and then cell D1 be filled in with another value.
Then when I type in a 2 in cell A2, it will fill in cell C2 with one value and E2 with another.

So basically there are certain pre-packaged values that I would like to be filled in and it would be nice to do that just by typing in a number instead of going through individually and filling all of them in

Comment: In **B1** use **=IF(A1=1,"BCol","")**, in **D1** use **=IF(A1=1,"DCol","")**, in **C2** use **=IF(A2=2,"CCol","")** and in **E2** use **=IF(A2=2,"ECol","")**, where you should replace **'N'Col** with whatever you need (pre-packaged values). If you're asking something else, there is not enough info, so add some more by using the **edit** button below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in cells A1, B1 and D1 related by a mathematical form? There is one way this can be done but not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Source(https://www.howtogeek.com/279148/how-to-automatically-fill-sequential-data-into-excel-with-the-fill-handle/)

To skip a column when filling a linear series, enter the first number in the first cell and then select that cell and one adjacent cell (for example, the next cell in the next column).Then, drag the fill handle across until you fill the desired number of cells. More details are available in the above link.